# How to avoid mirroring libraries in IntelliJ IDEA using gradle?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, gradle

I would like to avoid something like this in my project settings:

[image: Project Settings>Libraries]

Whenever I refresh gradle project libraries named "Gradle: " are regenerated and whenever I launch project in IntelliJ libraries without "Gradle: " are regenerated (in spite of deleting them).

Answer (score 1):

Just disable auto-import by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+S</kbd> (or File -> Settings...) and deselecting a checkbox:

[image]

Comment: thanks for help, but I have it deselected. When I "Force refresh all linked Gradle projects" it generates mirror libraries.

Comment: I may not get it, but this is a command which forces libraries to reload from the Gradle project definition. It's the same with Maven. May be an easier option would be to drop non-mirrorred duplicates?

Answer (score 0):

Your project was created with IntelliJ EAP version where libraries were imported without the prefix. You have to delete manually all unused libraries (without perfix) and refresh the project.

Comment: I deleted them, but hopelessly after reopen project they are recreated